scale_fill_gradient2 colors do not reach the upper limit, even though the data does
I am trying to illustrate values diverging from 0 in a heat map. However, values near, and beyond the maximum appear much paler than the specified high color.
library(ggplot2)

genotype <- c(rep(c("A", "B"), times = 8))
gene <- rep(c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "g5", "g6", "g7", "g8"),
            times = 2)
response <- c(-0.3026690, -2.5850300, -4.9285293, -7.5158563,
              2.2674635, -0.2312305, 3.7952988, -1.5507423,
              4.2041790, 1.1214478,  0.4004754, -1.9283537,
              2.1161335, -7.0709069, 2.8636382, -0.1685422)
d <- data.frame(genotype, gene, response)

ggplot(d, aes(x = genotype, y = gene, fill = response)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#8E0152", mid = "#F7F7F7", high = "#276419", 
                       limits=c(-7, 4), midpoint = 0, oob = scales::squish) 


Because two values are very near or above the upper limit of 4, I expect those tiles in the heat map to look dark green, near, or equal to "#276419". Instead, those tiles are a paler green.
heat map with pale green values where "#276419" was specified:


If you want a dark green color for the upper limit then perhaps you want scale_fill_gradientn? Even when setting the limits with scale_fill_gradient2 the colors are evenly spaced or positioned along the gradient, i.e. gradient runs from a dark red at -7 to a dark green at +7. Hence, a value of 4 will be colored in a paler shade of green. This can be fixed using the values= argument of scale_fill_gradientn which allows for an uneven spacing of the colors.
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d, aes(x = genotype, y = gene, fill = response)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colors = c("#8E0152", "#F7F7F7", "#276419"),
    values = scales::rescale(c(-7, 0, 4), to = c(0, 1)),
    limits = c(-7, 4),
    oob = scales::squish
  )



If you want to set colors for specific values, use scale_gradientn() and specifiy both colors and values.The values need to be normalized: you can use scale_fill_gradientn(
colors = c("#8E0152","#F7F7F7","#276419"),
values = scales::rescale(c(min(d$response), 0, max(d$response)))
)

scale_fill_gradientn with scales::rescale worked perfectly.  Thank you!
